Where can I find Babette after Dawnguard arc?
I completed the Dark Brotherood story, so

 only Nazir and Babette survived and now they live in Dawnstar sanctuary

I want to train my Alchemy skill with Babette, since she is the only master level trainer in Skyrim, but I can't find her after I completed the Dawnguard arc.
Babette's wiki page states that:

In Dawnguard, Babette becomes a random encounter, found wandering the wilderness of Skyrim in search of a "snack."

Is there any known location where she can be encountered? Or a way to find her easily?

Luckily she may appear at the Dark Brotherhood sanctuary sometimes, so she is not always wandering Skyrim.
Just waiting through the menu option should work.
